Spring Shell ComponentFlow and locale
How do I accept non-english characters when using ComponentFlow in Spring Shell?
It works fine with non-english characters when using the Shell normally, but when using the ComponentFlow it does not. When you press a key, it seems to ignore the input.
@ShellComponent
public class TestCommand {
    @ShellMethod(key = "test-locale")
    public String testLocale() {
        logger.info("Terminal is not null. Charset: " + terminal.encoding().displayName());

        ComponentFlow flow = componentFlowBuilder.clone()
                .withStringInput("testString").and().build();
        
        ComponentFlowResult result = flow.run();

        return "testString = " + result.getContext().get("testString");
    }
}

pom.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="https://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="https://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="https://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.2</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>group</groupId>
    <artifactId>artifact</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>name</name>
    <properties>
        <java.version>21</java.version>
        <spring-shell.version>3.3.1</spring-shell.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.shell</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-shell-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.shell</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-shell-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.shell</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-shell-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-shell.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <build>
        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>

The output of the above is UTF-8, but it's still not accepting non-english characters.

This is currently not supported in flow components. There's partial support in other parts so I created 1115 to handle it in StringInput as well.

Thank you. It now works with 3.4.0-SNAPSHOT :-)
